# Function which takes variadic function as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, arguments

I'm trying to create function which takes variadic function as parameter, but I can't figure out how to do it in a proper way. This is my try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

int add(int args, ...) {
    int res = 0;

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, args);

    for(int i=0; i < args; ++i)
        res += va_arg(ap, int);

    va_end(ap);

    return res;
}

int func(int (*func_arg)(int args, ...)) {
    return func_arg; //error
}

int main() {
    cout << add(2, 1, 2) << endl; //working
    cout << func(add(2, 1, 2)); //error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variadic C style functions aren't type safe. If I pass a float to your function, there are no complaints from the compiler but I get a garbage value back. You can look into variadic template functions to say you only accept ints and then the compiler will complain about a float. You also won't need to provide the number of arguments as the first argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This here...

```
func(add(2, 1, 2))
```

... calls the function `add` and tries to pass the result into `func`. That's making a pointer out of an integer without a cast, etc. So you get an error.

To pass the function itself (after the suitable function to pointer conversion) you'd do this:

```
func(add)
```

However, your implementation of `func` tries to return an integer by converting the function pointer. I strongly suspect that's not what you want. If you intend to call the variadic function, you can do this:

```
int func(int (*func_arg)(int args, ...)) {
    return func_arg(2, 1, 2);
}
```

But that of course hard-codes the arguments. You'd need to work out a slight design change if you wish to allow passing arguments as well.

---

Having said all that, if you wish to support callers of `func` passing in anything that may return an integer, you can use the library type `std::function` to accomplish that. Then your function will become something like this:

```
int func(std::function<int()> func_arg) {
    return func_arg(); //Invoke the callable
}
```

And the call site will be able to adapt to it with a simple lambda:

```
func([]{ return add(2, 1, 2); })
```

Which will come together into the effect you seem intent on achieving.